# React Native animated input text

Tags: react-native, animation, absolute

I want to show a cancel button, on the focus TextInput animation.
I did the following code, but a cancel button does not display and follow the box when focused. It's only shown after the animation end.

And when cancel button displayed, it is not on the same line with textinput.
How do I fix this?

```
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const PADDING = 16;
const SEARCH_FULL_WIDTH = width - PADDING * 2;  //search_width when unfocused
const SEARCH_SHRINK_WIDTH = width - PADDING - 90;  //search_width when focused

class Search extends React.Component {

constructor(props: IProps) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    inputLength: new Animated.Value(SEARCH_FULL_WIDTH),
    searchBarFocused: false,
  }
}

private onFocus = () => {
  Animated.timing(this.state.inputLength, {
    toValue: SEARCH_SHRINK_WIDTH,
    duration: 250,
  }).start(() => this.setState({ searchBarFocused: true }));
}

private onBlur = () => {
  Animated.timing(this.state.inputLength, {
    toValue: SEARCH_FULL_WIDTH,
    duration: 250,
  }).start(() => this.setState({ searchBarFocused: false }));
}


<View style={styles.searchContainer}>
<Animated.View style={[
  styles.search,
  {
    width: this.state.inputLength,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 16,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  searchBarFocused === true ? undefined : { justifyContent: 'center' }
]}>
  <Image source={searchIcon} style={styles.image} />
  <TextInput
    style={styles.searchInput}
    ....
    onBlur={this.onBlur}
    onFocus={this.onFocus}
  />
</Animated.View>

{searchBarFocused &&
  <Touchable style={styles.cancelSearch} onPress={this.cancelSearch}>
    <Text style={styles.cancelSearchText}>Cancel</Text>
  </Touchable>
}
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  searchContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 72,
    borderBottomColor: SOLITUDE_COLOR,
  },
  search: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 6,
  },
  cancelSearch: {
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

gif: when unfocus and focused
[image: vqhdHj]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version of your code.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Dimensions,
  View,
  Animated,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";

const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
const PADDING = 16;
const SEARCH_FULL_WIDTH = width - PADDING * 2; //search_width when unfocused
const SEARCH_SHRINK_WIDTH = width - PADDING - 90; //search_width when focused

const AnimatedTouchable = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(TouchableOpacity);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputLength: new Animated.Value(SEARCH_FULL_WIDTH),
      cancelPosition: new Animated.Value(0),
      opacity: new Animated.Value(0),
      searchBarFocused: false
    };
  }

  onFocus = () => {
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(this.state.inputLength, {
        toValue: SEARCH_SHRINK_WIDTH,
        duration: 250
      }),
      Animated.timing(this.state.cancelPosition, {
        toValue: 16,
        duration: 400
      }),
      Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 250
      })
    ]).start();
  };

  onBlur = () => {
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(this.state.inputLength, {
        toValue: SEARCH_FULL_WIDTH,
        duration: 250
      }),
      Animated.timing(this.state.cancelPosition, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 250
      }),
      Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 250
      })
    ]).start();
  };

  render() {
    const { searchBarFocused } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.search,
            {
              width: this.state.inputLength,
              position: "absolute",
              left: 16,
              alignSelf: "center"
            },
            searchBarFocused === true ? undefined : { justifyContent: "center" }
          ]}
        >
          <TextInput
            style={styles.searchInput}
            onBlur={this.onBlur}
            onFocus={this.onFocus}
            placeholder="Type something"
          />
        </Animated.View>

        <AnimatedTouchable
          style={[styles.cancelSearch, { right: this.state.cancelPosition }]}
          onPress={() => null}
        >
          <Animated.Text
            style={[styles.cancelSearchText, { opacity: this.state.opacity }]}
          >
            Cancel
          </Animated.Text>
        </AnimatedTouchable>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  searchContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    height: 72,
    borderBottomColor: "#00000033",
    paddingTop: 100
  },
  search: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: "red"
  },
  cancelSearch: {
    position: "absolute",
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    textAlign: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignSelf: "center"
  }
});
```

[image: textinput-animation]

Comment: can I ask you 1 question: How to make the text placeholder move like an animation? We will not use `placeholder` of TextInput, right?

Comment: Yes, with placeholder we might not be able to do much. You might have to make use of an absolute positioned Text component

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `searchBarFocused` only after your animation completes. Since the cancel button is conditionally rendered based on `searchBarFocused`, it only appears at the end of the animation.